# React time based function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an api post function that sends when the timeout reaches 45 seconds and when the user clicks the cancel button the post request stops or you clear the timeout to stop it.
I did something that works but after another 45 secs it makes another post requirement. is there way to make the post request after the 45 seconds and then cancel the request when user clicks the cancel button

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styles from "styles/jss/nextjs-material-kit/pages/components.js";
import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";
import Time from "components/Time.js"
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'


const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

function processorder({ query: { name, number, location, ordermessage, price, } }) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [processed, setProcessed] = useState(false)
    const [canceled, setCanceled] = useState(false)
    const [time, setTime] = useState()
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    const Id = setTimeout(() => {

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Api-key': 'ml7h7L8nN8Q2yA',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                client: name,
                client_phone: number,
                restaurant: "Chitis",
                location: location,
                ordermessage: "Jollof Rice",
                amount: "500"
            })
        };
        fetch('https://munche-bot.herokuapp.com/api/v1/orders', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                setData(result.data)
                setProcessed(true);
                return () => clearTimeout(Id)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));



    }, 45000);


    const cancel = () => {


        clearTimeout(Id);
        setCanceled(true);
        if (canceled == true) {
            alert("canceled")
        }
    };






    return (

       <div>

        <h3> processing Order<h3>
          (processed == false ? (<h3>proceed to payment in <Time/> <h3>) : (<h3>processed proceeding      to payment</h3>)

(canceled == false ? (<Button  onClicK={cancel} />) : <h3>order canceled</h3>


       
      </div>
    )
}
processorder.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
    return { query }
};

export default processorder
```

Comment: It's because you set the state after you make the api call, this causes a re-render which results in the code running once more and so on. This can go on forever. Ideally you would solve this with some sort of useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your whole timeout function in an if, which is dependant on state. However, this isn't very robust as changing the data or the time also sends a duplicate request:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styles from "styles/jss/nextjs-material-kit/pages/components.js";
import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";
import Time from "components/Time.js"
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'


const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

function processorder({ query: { name, number, location, ordermessage, price, } }) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [processed, setProcessed] = useState(false)
    const [canceled, setCanceled] = useState(false)
    const [time, setTime] = useState()
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    if (!canceled && !processed) {

      const Id = setTimeout(() => {

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Api-key': 'ml7h7L8nN8Q2yA',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                client: name,
                client_phone: number,
                restaurant: "Chitis",
                location: location,
                ordermessage: "Jollof Rice",
                amount: "500"
            })
        };
        fetch('https://munche-bot.herokuapp.com/api/v1/orders', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                setData(result.data)
                setProcessed(true);
                return () => clearTimeout(Id)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));



      }, 45000);
    }


    const cancel = () => {


        clearTimeout(Id);
        setCanceled(true);
        if (canceled == true) {
            alert("canceled")
        }
    };






    return (

       <div>

        <h3> processing Order<h3>
          (processed == false ? (<h3>proceed to payment in <Time/> <h3>) : (<h3>processed proceeding      to payment</h3>)

(canceled == false ? (<Button  onClicK={cancel} />) : <h3>order canceled</h3>


       
      </div>
    )
}
processorder.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
    return { query }
};

export default processorder
```

It would probably be better for you to do the whole fetch & timeout inside a clickHandler, with the timeout checking that `canceled` is false before sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styles from "styles/jss/nextjs-material-kit/pages/components.js";
import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";
import Time from "components/Time.js"
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'


const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

function processorder({ query: { name, number, location, ordermessage, price, } }) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [processed, setProcessed] = useState(false)
    const [canceled, setCanceled] = useState(false)
    const [time, setTime] = useState()
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const [id, setId] = useState()

    const cancel = () => {
        clearTimeout(id);
        setCanceled(true);
        if (canceled == true) {
            alert("canceled")
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const Id = setTimeout(() => {

            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Api-key': 'ml7h7L8nN8Q2yA',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    client: name,
                    client_phone: number,
                    restaurant: "Chitis",
                    location: location,
                    ordermessage: "Jollof Rice",
                    amount: "500"
                })
            };
            fetch('https://munche-bot.herokuapp.com/api/v1/orders', requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result)
                    setData(result.data)
                    setProcessed(true);
                    clearTimeout(Id);
                })
                .catch(error => console.log('error', error));



        }, 45000);
        setId(Id);

        console.log(data)
    }, []);





    
    return (

       <div>

        <h3> processing Order<h3>
          (processed == false ? (<h3>proceed to payment in <Time/> <h3>) : (<h3>processed proceeding      to payment</h3>)

(canceled == false ? (<Button  onClicK={cancel} />) : <h3>order canceled</h3>


       
      </div>
    )
}
processorder.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
    return { query }
};

export default processorder
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this should fix the issue and what you change ?